# Can not append to OpenSSL Cipher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I am running into a bit of trouble creating a cipher, Strange thing is if I run the script in irb or as a .rb file out side of my ROR application everything works fine.

Heres my Script.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/sha1'

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("bf-cbc").encrypt
cipher.key_len = 16
cipher.key= "random encryption key*"
v = cipher.random_iv.unpack("H*").first
xs = ((cipher << Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("you@example.com")) + cipher.final).unpack("H*").first
```

Error:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for  OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x007f800b60c920
```

I tried replacing << with push and I get the same error.

IRB
Ruby: 1.8.7

Application Details
Ruby: 1.9.2
Rails: 3.0.6

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: try `v.is_a? Array`, and puts it for us.

Comment: did v.is_a? Array, returned false. I then did v.is_a and it returned String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<` method on cipher was deprecated in 1.8.7 and removed in 1.9 (see the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-3C-3C)). It looks like you should be using the `update` method instead.

At a guess you have multiple versions of ruby installed, in such a way that the default version invoked is 1.8.7, but your rails app is running 1.9 or newer. This could be because of a .ruby-version file, a .rvmrc file or because rails is only installed for one of those versions.